# Actual size of NSView Self

Tags: objective-c, nsview, self, bounds

I just started a brandnew project GrafLaboratory to do some experimenting on drawing in NSView.
I added a custom view to the main window and configured it to adopt it´s size when the window changes it´s size.

I modified my InitFrameWith to this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSRect r = [self bounds];
    }

    return self;
}
```

When I start my new app the first time and ask for [self bounds] I get the correct value: {{0, 50}, {600, 450}}. I then change the size of the window by dragging with the mouse. When restarting my app initWithFrame returns the same value: {{0, 50}, {600, 450}}.

But I the new changed size. I already tried several things but without success.

Any clues what I´m doing wrong?

Thanks, Ronald

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initWithFrame is only relevant when you initialize the object within a frame.

If it's a custom UIView with custom drawing, then look at:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)frame
```

That will get called when setNeedsDisplay is called and/or the view is resized.

With some custom views, one thing I've done in initWithFrame is to set the autoresize masks:

```
    // subviews autoresize
    [self setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];   
    // set resize masks (springs)
    [self setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewMaxXMargin | NSViewMinXMargin |
                              NSViewMaxYMargin | NSViewMinYMargin |
                              NSViewHeightSizable | NSViewWidthSizable)];
```

Then in both init and drawRect, I call my layoutViews metod if the rect has changed:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)frame {
    ...
    // called on resize.  on init, delegate isn't hooked up so we'll skip
    if (!NSEqualRects(_prevRect, [self bounds]))
    {
        [self layoutViews];
    }

    // stash away rect for comparison so layout view code only happens when the rect changes
    _prevRect = [self bounds];
```

My layoutViews has custom layout logic.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, that sounds great. I find it strange that drawRect returns {{0, 50}, {600, 450}} on the very first call. All following calls return the correct size: see this Logs:
2012-10-11 06:12:29.035 GrafLaboratory[14723:303] rectBounds drawRect:: {{0, 0}, {600, 450}}
2012-10-11 06:12:29.069 GrafLaboratory[14723:303] rectBounds drawRect:: {{0, 0}, {1041, 803}}
2012-10-11 06:17:47.643 GrafLaboratory[14723:303] rectBounds drawRect:: {{0, 0}, {1039, 796}}
2012-10-11 06:17:47.658 GrafLaboratory[14723:303] rectBounds drawRect:: {{0, 0}, {1039, 795}}